# Removing some characters from string in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a link like this :

```
 Https://example.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css
```

How can I remove `Https://example.com/` and `/bootstrap.css` from this link?

the final result has to be this : `assets/css`

But actually this link is dynamic and not just static

What can I do?

Comment: The answer here depends highly on context. How did you get the link string and what will you do with the answer? Depending on that information there may be different tools available to you that already have this data, without needing to do the work of parsing out the string.

Comment: [Uri.Segments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=net-6.0) would probably be useful here

Comment: Which parts are static? Is it always a URL and you want to remove the protocol, domain, and file name (just get the path relative to the root)?

Comment: Just I want to get the name of directory which the file "bootstrap.css" is in it.

Comment: Every parts are dynamic.

Comment: It would help a lot if you [explained what goal you are trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), not just what method you have decided to use. Suppose you could “get the name of directory”; what are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

1. Create a `System.Uri` from the string
2. Break it apart into `.Segments`
3. Drop the last segment (the filename). (with `.Take(length-1)` or `.SkipLast(1)`)
4. Concatenate the remaining segments back together with `string.Join`
5. Drop the trailing `/` using `.TrimEnd`

.NET Framework:

```cs
var uri = new Uri("Https://example.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css");
string result = string.Join("", uri.Segments.Take(uri.Segments.Length-1)).TrimEnd('/');
```

.NET Standard:

```cs
string result = string.Join("", new Uri("Https://example.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css")
   .Segments.SkipLast(1)).TrimEnd('/');
```